# EF Code First relationship errors

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

So this is my first time doing a large project with EF Code first and im running into errors with my relationships. Here are my models:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public override string Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Trainer Trainer { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}

public class Trainer
{
    public Trainer()
    {
        Client = new HashSet<Client>();
    }
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string TrainerId { get; set; }
    ...
    public ICollection<Client> Client { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public virtual Trainer Trainer { get; set; }                          
    public virtual PhysicalAddress PhysicalAddress { get; set; }      
    public virtual BillingInfo BillingInfo { get; set; }
}

public class PhysicalAddress
{
    public string PhysicalAddressId{ get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}

public class BillingInfo
{
    public string BillingInfoId { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

Basically im trying to make a Seed method to make a Client. I already have one working for a Trainer but get a bunch of different errors with the different things I've tried for making a Client. This is the method im trying to run

```
var user = new ApplicationUser
{
    UserName = "Client@a.com",
    Email = "Client@a.com"
};
var client = new Client
{
    ApplicationUser = user,
    Trainer = manager.Find("Trainer@a.com", "P@ssw0rd").Trainer,
    PhysicalAddress = new PhysicalAddress
    {
        PhysicalAddressId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    },
    BillingInfo = new BillingInfo
    {
        BillingInfoId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    }
context.Client.Add(client);
manager.Create(user, "P@ssw0rd");
manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Client");
```

I've tried mapping the relationship with Fluent API but I get the error `An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasRequired(p => p.PhysicalAddress).WithOptional(p => p.Client);
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasRequired(p => p.Trainer).WithMany(p => p.Client);
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasRequired(p => p.BillingInfo).WithOptional(p => p.Client);
```

So I tried adding ForeignId's to the Client Model:

```
[ForeignKey("BillingInfo")]
public string BillingInfoId { get; set; }
```

But get the error `Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Client_BillingInfo_Source' in relationship 'Client_BillingInfo'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.`
Im not sure what else to try, please point me at what im doing wrong

**Update**:
After a few more hours spent on this problem I keep coming back to this error `Referential integrity constraint violation. A Dependent Role has multiple principals with different values`

Comment: Your `BillingInfo` requires a primary key (as does physical address). Actually, it seems *all* of your entities are missing primary keys.

Comment: @Rob Whops I didn't copy that bit of code over, edited it just now. They do all have Primary Keys, using the convention of ClassNameId

Comment: After your edit, it appears you have primary key *columns* defined, but you haven't told entity framework that they are primary keys. Add `[Key]` attributes over each primary key column

Comment: @Rob Ok changed them all over to have ``[Key]`` but now im getting the error ``An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types``

Comment: I would imagine that `manager.Find("Trainer@a.com", "P@ssw0rd").Trainer` is returning `null`, and it's preventing you from breaking the constraint `.HasRequired(p => p.Trainer)`

Comment: @Rob I've put it into the get method of a page load just so I can watch what it's doing in debug and that call is returning a trainer, but i've changed it so that im just making a new trainer each time just to be sure then assigning it to a the Client without a DB lookup.

Comment: I'd believe the error occurs on model creating between trainer and client. First of all, you should not mix fluent API with Data Annotation like this, it messes with the readability of your code. I don't really know enough about code first conventions, but I would assume EF tries to create a FK in client named TrainerId, but then get's confused as to what column it should be mapped to. According to code first conventions, Trainer.TrainerId should be targeted, but this column is an FK to ApplicationUser itself. You should map your relationships explicitly, not let conventions guide you.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro That makes a bit more sense thanks. I think you were right about not knowing where to map to so I fixed it by making the relationship as one to many with Fluent API this fixed the main problem, however I am still having issues making it work in the seed method, but that's another issue